# Matlab: create a new 3-dim array B using respective column elements of each dimension of array A

Tags: arrays, matlab

If I have an array e.g.

```
A(:,:,1) 
= 1 4 7
  2 5 8
  3 6 9
A(:,:,2)
= 10 13 16
  11 14 17
  12 15 16
A(:,:,3)
= 19 22 25
  20 23 26
  21 24 27
```

is there something like reshape, circshift that I can use to reorder it as follows:

```
B(:,:,1)
=  1 2 3
  10 11 12
  19 20 21
B(:,:,2)
= 4  5  6
  13 14 15
  22 23 24
B(:,:,3)
= 7  8  9
  16 17 18
  25 26 27
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are basically permuting dimensions there, so we can simply use the MATLAB built-in [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) for the same, like so -

```
B = permute(A,[3,1,2])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick and easy solution

Comment: @Matlab_beginner If this solved your question, consider accepting it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work